# Looking For Free Global Bedrock Geology Data

Tags: data, geology

I've searched around for a freely available global bedrock geology data set, but I have yet to find one.  Anyone come across such dataset?

Comment: Not global, but it is for all of [Canada](http://gdr.ess.nrcan.gc.ca/e/viewer.htm).

Comment: Did you look at [OneGeology](http://portal.onegeology.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of useful links:

- [certmapper.cr.usgs.gov](https://certmapper.cr.usgs.gov/data/apps/world-maps/) - **ESRI SHP, WMS** - *World Geologic
  Maps Data Downloads. This page provides access to data from various
  USGS World Geologic Maps.*
- [catalog.data.gov](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=geology&sort=views_recent%20desc&tags=geology&res_format=ZIP&as_sfid=AAAAAAW5PbeAcqpx__p1fzj8tpiuBtZdLBTRud_ef7zmB138yjjqUd0fKWDNdl5pLhmWwTLqNkT-Q2PSZ5EyLzZanOOHrbQlJDAFIY8zwPDdJT6Pu6ZrdfcrmW-MlIQoG2J8UgQ%3D&as_fid=dd09b6deefb31f014876b017d174a3eae582b2aa&ext_location=&ext_bbox=&ext_prev_extent=-142.03125%2C-8.059229627200192%2C-59.0625%2C52.696361078274485#sec-res_format) - **ESRI SHP, WMS and other** - *Here you will find data, tools, and resources to conduct research, develop web
  and mobile applications, design data visualizations, and more. Quite
  scattered database but you can find generalized geology of continents
  and then merge it together.*
- [orrbodies.com](https://www.orrbodies.com/about/) - **MapInfo TAB** - divided into countries - *Compilation of digital databases from various forms of hardcopy regional and mine based exploration data.*
- [earthenv.org](http://www.earthenv.org/streams) - **NetCDF** - *Global, remote-sensing supported environmental layers for assessing status and trends in biodiversity,
  ecosystems, and climate*
- [onegeology-geonetwork.brgm.fr](http://onegeology-geonetwork.brgm.fr/geonetwork3/srv/eng/catalog.search#/search?facet.q=type%2Fdataset&resultType=details&sortBy=relevance&fast=index&_content_type=json&from=1&to=20&any=world) - **WMS/WFS** - *OneGeology material, which is defined as data, mapping, map extracts,
  illustrations, images (but not including institutional logos) which
  are available on the OneGeology website, is freely available for all
  uses.*
- [mrdata.usgs.gov](https://mrdata.usgs.gov/geology/world/) - **WMS/WFS** - General geologic map of the world -    *World geology compiled by the Geological Survey of Canada
  at    approximately 1:35,000,000 scale, published there as Open File
  Report 2915.*

Comment: note several OneGoleogy services have WFS as well as WMS